# Error in htmltools::validateCssUnit(width) : CSS units must be a single-element numeric or character vector!?!? Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Not sure what's happening, but it keeps telling me "Error in htmltools::validateCssUnit(width) :    CSS units must be a single-element numeric or character vector"....Been trying to search for reasons and can't seem to identify which piece of code is causing this error. I included the code with the error and the code I had previously that is working fine.

Error message when running:

```
#Libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library (plotly)
library(shinythemes)

#Load Data
data<-read_excel("C:/Users/Kanew/OneDrive/Desktop/RApp/Unemployment2.xlsx")
data$Date<-as.Date(data$MonthYear)

#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI #UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI

if (interactive()) {

#navbar includes fluidpage (fluid = TRUE)
ui <-navbarPage(
    
    
    #TAB 1 (Initial data display)
    "Unemployment Exploration", fluid = TRUE,
    tabPanel("Unemployment by Race",
            mainPanel(
                 
                h1("National Unemployment Rate by Race"),
                varSelectInput(
                inputId = "Category",
                label = "Select Race or National Rate",
                data,
                multiple = TRUE),
                     
            plotlyOutput("plot", ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x=Date, y = Rate, colour = Category)) +
                             geom_line() + 
                             xlab("Year") + ylab("Unemployment Rate (%)") +
                             scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18))+
                             scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years" , date_labels = "%Y")+
                             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
                             theme_economist() +
                             scale_fill_economist()),
                setBackgroundColor("#778899"),
                
            )),
    
    #TAB 2 (Data tables)
    tabPanel("Data",
             DT::dataTableOutput("data")))




#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server



server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    #Output for TAB 1
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
            
            if(length(input$Category) == 0) return (data)
                data %>% dplyr::select(!!!input$Category)},
            
               
               rownames = TRUE)}

        
    #Output for TAB 2
    
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(data)})
    
}
    



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

No error message:

```
#Libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(ggthemes)
library (plotly)
library(shinythemes)

#Load Data
data<-read_excel("C:/Users/Kanew/OneDrive/Desktop/RApp/Unemployment2.xlsx")
data$Date<-as.Date(data$MonthYear)

#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI #UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI#UI



#navbar includes fluidpage (fluid = TRUE)
ui <-navbarPage(
    
    
    #TAB 1 (Initial data display)
    "Unemployment Exploration", fluid = TRUE,
    tabPanel("Unemployment by Race",
             mainPanel(
                 plotlyOutput("plot", height = 'auto', width = 'auto'),
                 setBackgroundColor("#778899"),
                 
                 h1("National Unemployment Rate by Race"),
                 selectInput(
                     inputId = "Category",
                     label = "Select Race or National Rate",
                     choices = c("All",unique(data$Category)),
                     selected = "All"
                     
                 ))),
    
    #TAB 2 (Data tables)
    tabPanel("Data",
             DT::dataTableOutput("data")))




#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server#Server



server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    #Output for TAB 1
    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        data %>%
            filter(Category == input$Category | input$Category == "All") %>%
            ggplot(data, mapping = aes(x=Date, y = Rate, colour = Category)) +
            geom_line() + 
            xlab("Year") + ylab("Unemployment Rate (%)") +
            scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18))+
            scale_x_date(date_breaks = "years" , date_labels = "%Y")+
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
            theme_economist() +
            scale_fill_economist()
        
    })
    
    
    #Output for TAB 2
    
    output$data <- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(data)
        
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: you are passing a ggplot object to the second argument of `?plotlyOutput` which is `width - Must be a valid CSS unit (like "100%", "400px", "auto") or a number`

Comment: What is the issue with your previous working code? That is the correct way.

Comment: @RonakShah I was trying to add the functionality to choose which "categories" of unemployment to visualize on the display...currently it's only a dropdown with options of 1 or all at the same time.